# How to apply conditional check and execute the code while creating new object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, if-statement

I'm creating a new object of a class in my code as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var mail_list = $('#email_for_contact_us').val();

    new Taggle($('.delicious.textarea')[0], {
      tags: mail_list.split(',')
    });
});
```

When the variable `mail_list` contains a comma separated series of strings it's working fine.
The issue raises when the variable `mail_list` contains nothing(it's blank/empty).

I don't want to execute the statement `tags: mail_list.split(',')` when the variable `mail_list` is blank/empty.

How to do this in jQuery in above code? Can someone help me in this regard please?

Thanks in advance.

If you have any queries regarding the issue please do let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this to avoid an array containing a single empty string item.

```
tags: mail_list? mail_list.split(',') : []
```

Comment: I tried your trick and wrote the code as follows:
var mail_list = $('#email_for_contact_us').val();
    $(document).ready(function() {
    new Taggle($('.delicious.textarea')[0], {
      //tags: mail_list.split(',')
      tags : mail_list? mail_list.split(',') || []
    });
});
But it's giving syntax error as Expected : but found } and Expected ; but found )

Comment: @user2839497 Sorry, it's `:`, not `||` for the ternary operator... careless mistake ;) I fixed the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help plalx but my issue is still unresolved. Actually when the value is blank/empty the blank array [] is getting assigned which I also want to avoid. How to do this? I don't want to do anything when the variable mail_list is empty/blank.

Comment: @user2839497 So you do not want to create a new `Taggle` instance at all if `mail_list` is blank, or you mean that you want to pass `undefined` rather than an empty array?

Comment: Thanks for your help and interest in my issue. But I tried a trick and it resolved now. I wrote the following code:
var mail_list = $('#email_for_contact_us').val();
    
    new Taggle($('.delicious.textarea')[0], {

        tags: mail_list? mail_list.split(',') : ''
    });